# How to set a delay in Postam Runner using a csv file as input

Tags: javascript, postman

I'm using postman to test an API which is as follows: (this is a POST)

```
{
"contact_name": "{{contact_name}}",
"contact_email": "{{contact_email}}",
"answers": [
    {
        "question_id": 1,
        "value": "{{value_1}}"
    },
    {
        "question_id": 2,
        "value": "{{value_2}}"
    }
   ],
  "disable_email": true
}
```

I have an environment with the corresponding variables:

```
contact_name,contact_email,value_1,value_2
```

And I'm using the Runner to load a csv file that contains 100,000 rows.
In fact, it runs good, but I need to put a delay every 10,000 rows for example. Is there a way to perform this? I know that there is a way to set a delay in each iteration, but I'd like to know if there is a way to set a delay (30 secs) after 10,000 iterations.

Thanks!

Comment: just curious whats your RAM size to run such a huge CSV file ?

Comment: Hi!  I'm running it in a ubuntu machine with VM. 2 cores and 8 GB RAM, however, it only takes from 2.5 to 3 GB RAM to send all requests

Comment: are you using newman or collection runner

Comment: did the answer help

Answer (score 0):

**Add this to pre-request script**

```
if((pm.info.iteration+1)===10000){
setTimeout(()=>{},3000)
}
```

**This will wait for 3 second before sending the rquest for iteration 10000 , the count starts from '0' thats why adding 1 to that.**

Comment: Hi! when reaching the 10,000 requests, it fails. I receive a out of array error and script stops.This is how the pre-request script looks: pm.environment.set("contact" , data.contact);

pm.environment.set("value_1" , data.value_1);

pm.environment.set("value_2" , data.value_2);

if((pm.info.iteration+1)===10000){

setTimeout(()=>{},30000)

}   what could be the issue?

Comment: that doesn't have anything to do with this pre request , we are not accessing any array here .

Comment: try printing pm.info.iteration and see what you get

Answer (score 0):

It works! I just added another if sentence because the counter was reset everytime. This is how it worked:

```
var cont = parseInt(pm.environment.get('cont'));

if((pm.info.iteration)==0) {
    pm.environment.set("cont", 5000);
}

if((pm.info.iteration+1)==cont) {
    cont=cont+5000;
    setTimeout(()=>{},120000);
    pm.environment.set("cont", cont);
}
```

(in this example, i'm setting that every 5000 iterations i'm setting a delay of 2 minutes)
And for any reason, postman reads all variables as strings, I didn't know this